# How to properly convert to a canonical string for searching in Cocoa?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, search, unicode

I have a string field that I know that users will want to search on later. Inspired by the WWDC 2012 Core Data Best Practices session I plan to store a normalized version of the string into a separate field so I can optimize my search predicates.

My primary concern is case insensitivity, but while I'm normalizing strings I figure that I should also normalize the unicode representation. But I want to be sure I use the right normalization form (i.e. C,D,KC or KD). And does it matter whether I convert to lowercase first? (Localization is not my strong suit.)

So:

1. What are the proper methods to call to do the search normalization of the NSString?
2. What would be the optimal way to make sure the normalized version is stored.

I will post my first attempt as an answer, but I'd love to hear where I am wrong, other suggestions, or improvements. (Unfortunately while they showed the search predicates in that video, I don't think they showed the code from the session.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the use case you describe, it doesn't matter whether you pick precomposed or decomposed (C or D; although you will save a bit of space with precomposed), but think carefully about whether you want canonical or compatibility (K forms). [TR15](http://unicode.org/reports/tr15/) has a nice figure that summarises the differences (Figure 6):

[image]

That is: if someone searches for "ſ" (a '[long s](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long_s)') do you want to match "s" (and vice versa)? These are regarded as "formatting distinctions", so you shouldn't replace the text the user enters with these forms (as you lose data), but you may want to ignore them when searching.

With regard to a case-insensitive comparison, it's not enough to simply make both strings lowercase and compare them. It will work for English, but there are languages where the mapping between lower and uppercase (if such a distinction even exists) is no so clear. The W3C wiki has a [nice summary of these "case folding" issues](http://www.w3.org/International/wiki/Case_folding). Unfortunately, you can't optimise this in your storage by keeping the data in one "case", you can only do a proper comparison when you know both strings and the locale.

Luckily, when working with an `NSString` it's [`-compare:options:range:locale:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/compare:options:range:locale:) lets you specify an `NSCaseInsensitiveSearch` option and the locale (if you know it), which will handle these case folding problems for you (also take a look at `NSDiacriticInsensitiveSearch` and `NSWidthInsensitiveSearch` to see if you want to be agnostic about those differences too).

Answer (score 0):

What I currently plan to do is override the setter for the field, like so:

```
- (void)setName:(NSString *)value
{
    [self willChangeValueForKey:@"name"];
    [self setPrimitiveValue:value forKey:@"name"];
    [self didChangeValueForKey:@"name"];

    //Store normalized for for searching
    [self willChangeValueForKey:@"searchName"];
    [self setPrimitiveValue:[[value lowercaseStringWithLocale:[NSLocale currentLocale]] decomposedStringWithCompatibilityMapping] forKey:@"searchName"];
    [self didChangeValueForKey:@"searchName"];
}
```

I also made the searchName property read-only.

Comment: Is this an answer, or an addendum to your initial question? If it's the latter, you should simply edit your initial question to include this information.

Comment: This is an answer. As I discussed at the end of the question, I provided the answer to the best of my own ability. In the hopes that someone would either validate my answer, point out faults/limitations, or provide a better answer.

Comment: Thanks for the edit Josh. Unfortunately I forgotten that SE doesn't support the Github extensions to Markdown.